# Transaction and Rollback in Spring with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

Hi friends of StackOverflow,
I do not understand how to roll back I read the documentation of Spring, but I still do not understand. Basically I'm going to persist an object in the db (with primary key manually) all the way here all right, the object is inserted into the db. But when you persist the object again with the same primary key I have caused an exception, and rightly so, a violation of restriction of uniqueness. In this case I would get a Transaction rollback and warn you that there was the problem and continue running the program

This is my class:

```
public class ServiceDaoImpl{

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="fb-persistence")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void write(Service entity){
        try {
            em.persist(entity);
            em.flush();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
    * .. other method
    */
}
```

And this is the stack of error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:798)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy27.flush(Unknown Source)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.write(GenericDaoImpl.java:236)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.EnteDaoImpl.write(EnteDaoImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy34.write(Unknown Source)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.ConfigTest.insertEnte(ConfigTest.java:47)
    at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.ConfigTest.main(ConfigTest.java:32)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: violata restrizione di unicità (FLUSSIBATCH.SYS_C008896)
```

and my configuration files are (persistence.xml and applicationContext.xml):

This is the applicationContext.xml:
    ...

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fb-persistence" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/> 
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean name="serviceDaoImpl" class="it.synclab.fb.jpa.dao.impl.ServiceDaoImpl" />
...

This is the persistence.xml:
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="fb-persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>it.entity.Service</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="############"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="############"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/> 
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:629)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9467)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
        ... 27 more
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy34.write(Unknown Source)
        at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.ConfigTest.insertEnte(ConfigTest.java:47)
        at it.synclab.fb.jpa.test.ConfigTest.main(ConfigTest.java:32)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
        ... 9 more
```

Why have to be complicated? I just do not understand ... I hope some of you have had the same problem and solved

Comment: I want to handle the exception of ConstraintViolationException to launch the custom exception, so I need to do a rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but your problem might be with `ServiceDaoImpl` exception handling:

```
try {
     em.persist(entity);
     em.flush();
} catch(Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is a **really bad practice** (tm). Don't catch the exception but let it pop up from your method. This way:

1. Transaction demarcation mechanism will intercept the exception and mark transaction as rollback only
2. You won't ignore the exception (yes, catching and logging is almost as bad as swallowing)
3. Very likely the exception will be caught at some higher level and logged properly (using SLF4J or similar) and you won't have this boilerplate.

So to cut long story short:

```
public class ServiceDaoImpl{

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="fb-persistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void write(Service entity){
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
    }

}
```

Note that you don't need setter for `EntityManager` and the field can be private.

Comment: So I have to catch the exception in the top layer of the application

Comment: No, if your desired behavior is "*rollback if runtime exception occurs*" than simply do nothing, let the exception flow. After all, this why would you use automatic transaction management? Handle the exception manually only if you want to perform some extra work before rollback. However make sure you rethrow the exception - otherwise the container will not be able to discover that the transaction should be rolled back.

Comment: In what sense? What should I check?

Comment: I am not following... Just don't catch the exception and you'll be fine :-).

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block in your write method and throw an exception in case of error.

Put a `rollbackFor` or `rollbackForClassname` attribute in your `@Transactional` annotation for the exception that you rise, if you want to controll rollback events.

Comment: This won't help him because the exception is never thrown from this method (it is being swallowed).

Comment: yes, He can add an exception throw and controll it with rollback classfor, I edit my post

Comment: It'ok, but if I have another type of exception will be swallowed, as rightly pointed @TomaszNurkiewicz